# Configure Backing Field of Different Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent

```cs
        private int _billAccount;
        public string BillAccount { get
            {
                var account = _billAccount.ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
                return account.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + account.Substring(3, 3) + "-" + account.Substring(6, 3);
            }
            set
            {
                var account = new string(value.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
                _billAccount = Convert.ToInt32(account);
            }
        }
```

The BillAccount property in the class handles the string presentation as (999-999-999).  The column in the table is defined as

```sql
BillAccount INT NOT NULL
```

I've tried using

```cs
.HasField("_billAccount")
.HasConversion(new NumberToStringConverter<int>())
```

and any other combination I can think of, but I just can't get it to work.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified field '_billAccount'
>   of type 'int' cannot be used for the property 'Lead.BillAccount' of
>   type 'string'. Only backing fields of types that are assignable from
>   the property type can be used

How can I configure this in EF Core 3, Fluent API so field `_billAccount` is mapped to table column `BillAccount`, even though they have a different types?

Comment: Keep `BillAccount` as `int` and use an unmapped property to do the translation.

Answer (score 1):

as @madreflection alluded to:

```cs
public class TheModel {

    private int _billAccount;
    private string _formattedBillAccount = string.Empty;
    public int BillAccount {
        get { return _billAccount; }
        set { 
            _billAccount = value;  
            _formattedBillAccount = value.ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
            _formattedBillAccount = $"{_formattedBillAccount.Substring(0, 3)}-{_formattedBillAccount.Substring(3, 3)}-{_formattedBillAccount.Substring(6, 3)}";
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FormattedBillAccount { get { return _formattedBillAccount; } }
}
```

Comment: Sort of... This definitely would work, but I was thinking more along the lines of having `FormattedBillAccount`'s `get` accessor create the string on demand, and it would have a `set` accessor that would parse it. Bidirectional translation in the accessors rather than a cached value in another field.

Comment: @madreflection: certainly.  I went with this route because I assumed that reading the formatted number would be a more common task than setting the value.  So this would minimize allocations and cpu time in that scenario.  But if reading is less common than setting the value then doing it in the get accessor would be great.  In either case adding a set accessor for bidirectional binding would be a good idea.. left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: All fair and excellent points. I deleted an earlier comment because it was a big can of worms, but I had suggested using a domain object that could parse account numbers (presumably from user input) and convert back to strings. It would then also be convertible to/from `int` as well, although I believe storing an account number as an int when that's meant to have a format is a bad design choice (another reason I withdrew it). Translation in the property would be an almost-pluggable interim step to that.

Comment: @madreflection The format is to make it easier to read by people in interfaces, but many of the related systems require it to be an int.  If I store the formatted version, I'd have to strip the formatting out for any downstream system.  The previous webforms version uses an int field with a formatted string property to faciliate both.